# ¿Como crear una funcion de mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Se supone que tengo que crear una función a partir de esta sentencia:

`select count(idepoc) as "Total" from padecimientos where idepoc=1;`

pero cuando la creo me marca un error.
esta es la funcion que creo:

```
delimiter //
 create function TotalEPOC() returns int
 begin 
 declare EPOC int;
 select count(idepoc) into EPOC from padecimientos where idepoc=1;
 return EPOC;
 end//
delimiter ;
```

Este es el error que me marca:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error no es legible, colócalo como texto por favor

Comment: error code 1418. this function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enable(you "might" want to use less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Comment: En el Botton que dice edición sirve para editar pregunta, editala y agrégale el mensaje de error en vez de imágenes porque en verdad no es legible la imagen

Comment: Huy 1año 0_0. ¿Como te fue?, ¿lo resolviste?